# Using admin uploaded images

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-media

In admin page I add some image to model `Product`. In my `settings.py` file i write this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath('media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('static', os.path.abspath('static')),
)
```

Uploaded image is placed in folder `media`. I want to display these images and write in template next:`<img src='{{ brand.product_image.url }}' alt=""/>` and write`{% load staticfiles %}` in the template, but image is not displayed.
What's the problem then?
And one more question: what's the better way to store images that are uploaded by admin: in `media` folder or in `static` folder?
And can I store images in app folder, where I use them?

My `Brand`model:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    product_image = models.ImageField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

My `template` code:

```
<div class="tab-pane  active" id="blockView">
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            {% for brand in brands %}
                <a href="{% url 'brand' brand_id=brand.id %}">
                <li class="span3">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src='{{ brand.product_image.url }}' alt=""/>
                    <div class="caption">
                      <h5>{{ brand.name }}</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                </a>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
    <hr class="soft"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: models looks good. May be your have mistake in template?
When you upload file in admin interface is   new file created in MEDIA_ROOT folder?

Comment: yes, new file is created in folder "media". I described in my question all that I did in template. Looks right

Comment: post template code pls

Comment: hmm, looks good. Your template generate some code in image src? Are you running django by runserver?

Comment: Yes, I'm running django by runserver. Template generates: <img src="/media/946692-coca-cola.jpg" alt="">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static and media files have different purpose. For uploaded files you should use media files. 
Static files are images, JavaScript, or CSS files which are included to your static template. So, if some images are part of your templates by default store they in `static` folder.

About not displayed image:
Please provide more information. Post your models.

Update - serve media and static on development server.

Update your urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',

)  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, show_indexes=True) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT, show_indexes=True)
```

Comment: Update, add last line to your projects urls.py

Comment: Thank you a lot. But why I need to add that url? Why so complicated?

Comment: more docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development.
I think by defaul your must serve static and media files with nginx or another http server.